# I'm unable to install twilio gem as I get an error installing install libxml

Tags: ruby, twilio, libxml-ruby

This is the error message I'm getting in CLI. I tried the solutions given in other posts like, `sudo gem install twilio-ruby` but that didn't work. I'm using a Mac with Sierra. I have ruby 2.4. Any help is appreciated as this is such a small part of a full on weekend challenge!! I'm having to add more words as I've posted mostly code so this is a ramble.

```
$ gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/davidhalewood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/ext/libxml
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20171006-71383-4z74id.rb extconf.rb
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ends with \r may cause a problem
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-xml2-config
    --without-xml2-config
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
 extconf failure: need libxml2.

    Install the library or try one of the following options to extconf.rb:

      --with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config
      --with-xml2-dir=/path/to/libxml2
      --with-xml2-lib=/path/to/libxml2/lib
      --with-xml2-include=/path/to/libxml2/include


To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/davidhalewood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/davidhalewood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/davidhalewood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/gem_make.out
[davidhalewood:...Projects/takeaway-challenge]$ cat /Users/davidhalewood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/libxml-ruby-3.0.0/mkmf.log
find_header: checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2... -------------------- no

"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib     -lruby.2.4.2  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"clang -E -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
/* end */

"clang -E -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe -I/opt/include/libxml2 conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
/* end */

"clang -E -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
/* end */

"clang -E -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
/* end */

"clang -E -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
/* end */
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install libxml2` and then `bundle install` again?

Comment: all I get is `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't "gem" and "bundle" using the same libxml2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466606/why-arent-gem-and-bundle-using-the-same-libxml2)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on MacOS Sierra. In my case the solution was to update Xcode tools :
`xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 1):

Reading the message, seems that you just need to install `libxml2`.

`sudo apt-get install libxml2`

Comment: Are you using MacOS?

Comment: Yes, but I've fixed the issue by removing Xcode and reinstalling. It must have corrupted somehow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running

```
gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0' -- --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include
```