# Bundle install fails to install libxml-ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm a new to Ruby world and I need to clone an existing project.

The instructions are:

```
source .env.development
bundle install
```

But it fails with:

```
Using libv8 3.16.14.15
Fetching libxml-ruby 2.9.0
Installing libxml-ruby 2.9.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/libxml-ruby-2.9.0/ext/libxml
/Users/vlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181109-46682-fvgifh.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/vlad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-xml2-config
--without-xml2-config
--with-xml2-dir
--without-xml2-dir
--with-xml2-include
--without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
--with-xml2-lib
--without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
 extconf failure: need libxml2.

    Install the library or try one of the following options to extconf.rb:

      --with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config
      --with-xml2-dir=/path/to/libxml2
      --with-xml2-lib=/path/to/libxml2/lib
      --with-xml2-include=/path/to/libxml2/include


To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.3.0/libxml-ruby-2.9.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/libxml-ruby-2.9.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.3.0/libxml-ruby-2.9.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libxml-ruby (2.9.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.9.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  upnxt_community_lib_common was resolved to 1.7.49, which depends on
    upnxt_processing_lib_document was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      libxml-
```

If I want to execute the command that is suggested "gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.9.0'" I get the same error.

Operating System: MacOS Mojave, version 10.14.
Ruby version needed for the project: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin18]

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550421/3018671) but it didn't helped.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `brew install libxml2`?

Comment: And if if still fails, `brew link --force libxml2`?

Comment: @TomLord, I tried this and it didn't worked

Comment: @NicuVlad it still says _"need libxml2"_?

Comment: @NicuVlad It's hard to diagnose the problem when all we hear back from suggestions is "didn't help" or "didn't work". Does the error message remain identical, or did it change? If the error has changed, then we've probably made some progress and now need to address a *different* issue.

Comment: @TomLord, the output was indentical

Comment: All of the people answering below are explaining how to install it with the gem command. The OP mentions that he's using Bundler. These gem steps do NOT help with the bundler command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't "gem" and "bundle" using the same libxml2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466606/why-arent-gem-and-bundle-using-the-same-libxml2)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I manage to fix this with the help of a colleague, if anybody else encounter this problem:

```
gem install libxml-ruby -v '2.9.0' -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.8/include/libxml2/libxml/ --with-xml2-config=/usr/bin/xml2-config
```

Replace '2.9.0' with the libxml version that you need!

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer though, because if you run Bundler again, the error is the same.

Answer (score 29):

These steps worked for me ([source](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/issues/315#issuecomment-493283073))

```
brew install libxml2
bundle config --global build.libxml-ruby --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config"
```

then `bundle install` worked as expected

Comment: Yup. Worked for me on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 5):

It solved for me in mac by running

gem install libxml-ruby -v '3.0.0' -- --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include

Comment: I add to update to 3.0.0 with this command to actually getting it working. thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

Just happened today.

```
$ brew link --force libxml2
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: libxml2
...
```

At first, I wasn't aware that there's a warning and it doesn't work anymore. 
Then found this [workaround](https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby/issues/140#issuecomment-428337700) and it worked for me.

```
bundle config build.libxml-ruby --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/
```

Comment: With Mojave I needed to remove the `--use-system-libraries=true` switch.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered many tips while googling around today. I've tried to compile them into a logical order of some things to try:

**[Installing/debugging libxml on mac for ruby/rails.](https://gist.github.com/harry-wood/83b9c2c07b604524a23a4d2b88584a0f)**

There's a lot on this page already. But just to point out a few extra things I've gathered from elsewhere.

To me it seems more sensible to try to get a working `bundle config` command than to bypass this with a `gem install` command. So use skplunkerin's answer, or...

The following will configure it to use the system libxml headers:

```
bundle config --global build.libxml-ruby --with-xml2-include=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include/libxml2
bundle install
```

...which worked better for me today. The libxml-ruby gem build was having issues with the latest homebrew installed libxml vs an older system libxml.